isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
I'm getting an error message when trying to train my model, but some reason its giving me the same message every time I alter it.
Here is the code:

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainArgument(
    output_dir="bert_results",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="bert_results/logs",
    logging_steps=10,
)



# Initialize the TFTrainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    loss_function=("categorical_crossentropy")
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()




What I am getting in return "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jesh\PycharmProjects\Yelp\finetuning.py", line 44, in <module>
    trainer = Trainer(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jesh\PycharmProjects\Yelp\venv\Lib\site-packages\tftrainer\trainer.py", line 32, in __init__
    if isinstance(callable, loss_function)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union" 

I am working on a machine learning project where I expect my fine-tuned model to be produced after running a specific script. This script involves training a model using a custom trainer class. Despite making various modifications to the trainer class to improve the training process, I consistently encounter an error related to the model's state.
The specific error message is: "sate error." This error suggests that there is an issue with the state management of the model during or after the training process.

Isn't it telling you?  The loss function  argument is supposed to be a function.  You're passing a string.

That code just looks like a bug; shouldn't it be isinstance(loss_function, Callable)?

Try removing the loss_function argument from the Trainer. I could not find its existance.
# Initialize the TFTrainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset
)

I also noticed that you are using TFTrainer, which doesn't seem to be supported by the latest version of transformers. I checked some old docs for transformers and still didn't manage to find that argument.
If you need to do have a custom loss function, please see this HF thread. Essentially, you must subclass the Trainer and override the compute_loss method. In your case, it would be subclassing TFTrainer.

According to this,
If you pass invalid loss_function, the default behavior is to use tf.keras.losses.loss_function.
But, passing a string throws an error because isinstance expects a type or a union of types, not a string.
And since, you were passing 'categorical_crossentropy', I think you intended to use the tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy function.
To fix that error, you should replace the string with tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy.
like:
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    loss_function=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
)

